# Slot Machine Games for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

My sister is looking for any linux slot machine games. She has pretty much tapped out all of the Chrome Apps slot games. Any other suggestions that are maybe installable with a DEB perhaps? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slot machine game called [BFruit](http://bfruit.sourceforge.net/), but it's not packaged for Ubuntu. However, is only a matter of [downloading it from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bfruit/files/bfruit/0.1.2/bfruit-0.1.2.tar.bz2/download) and running the `bfruit.py` script inside the tarball. Just remember to install the [python-pygame](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-pygame) package first.

[image]

To play, press <kbd>left</kbd> to spin and <kbd>up</kbd> to raise the bet.